# CSS 3D support on Mozilla,Chrome,Opera

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, opera, mozilla

Hi ALL
I am working on 3D Data rendering and I am not able to find out the equivalent of following in mozilla, opera, chrome

Can anybody help me out  from this problem.

for e.g:

```
-webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(200px) rotateY(90deg) rotateZ(90deg);
```

Thanks,

Amit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chrome is webkit (prefix `-webkit` like you arleady use it)

mozilla is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-transform) (first hit on [google](http://www.google.de/#hl=de&expIds=17259,23756,24878,26637,26992&xhr=t&q=mozilla+css+transform&cp=21&pf=p&sclient=psy&aq=f&aqi=g1g-o1&aql=&oq=mozilla+css+transform&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=d11203eb09cce9f0)) (prefix `-moz`)

```
-moz-transform:  rotate(30deg);
```

opera is [this](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/css3-transitions-and-2d-transforms/) ([google](http://www.google.de/#sclient=psy&hl=de&q=opera+css+transform&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=d11203eb09cce9f0)) (prefix `-o`)

```
-o-transform: translateX(50px);
-o-transform: translateY(100px);
```

**EDIT:** [this](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/06/3d-transforms-isocube/) shows a 3d-effect in mozilla. maybe that helps.

Comment: rotate is far more different than rotateX and rotateY. Please refer to the link http://webkit.org/blog/386/3d-transforms/

Comment: i think "skew" is what you're searching. take a look at the mozilla link again.

Comment: y aren't they doing any standards for this ?

Comment: @Omu — because they are in the very early experimental stage (hence the use of vendor prefixes). They are trying stuff out to see what works before standardising.

Answer (score 1):

3D CSS transforms (translateZ, rotateY, matrix3d etc.) are available only in Webkit (Safari and Chromium on Windows). No Opera at this time. Heard some rumors that Fox will support it someday, so maybe...

Answer (score 0):

**A really good article on this Subject is available here:**
http://24ways.org/2010/intro-to-css-3d-transforms